# What would the markings above these pads mean? Trying to hack this watch

Tags: hardware, hacking

Here is an image of the watch:

[image: Watch photo]
*([Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDkJu.jpg))*

Here is an image of the pads in question:

[image: Pads photo]
*([Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yseB3.jpg))*

I am not very knowledgeable about hardware as I come from a software background. Could anyone lead me in a direction, particularly one that explains what these pads would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just exposed copper pads known as "test points" but also used for programming and troubleshooting. They offer hardware engineers a relatively easy way to probe to view signals, program firmware, or perform calibration and diagnostic tasks during manufacturing.

The silkscreen labels which you are referring to are going to be specific to the product. One of them appears to be "SDA" which would commonly be serial data, seen in I2C communications, for example. Above that test point might be "3V3" which would be for measuring voltage. It's very hard to make out most of them.

Comment: I see, yea it just a chinese smart watch, called a Hello Watch I think. It has an XMC XM25QH128 chip it seems. Would there be a way to get data from the serial test point?

Comment: The tools you'd want to use would be an oscilloscope and/or a logic analyzer. Some oscilloscopes have built-in serial decoding (or as a paid software option).